# Android ViewPager2 with fragment containing a recyclerview not scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-viewpager2

I'm using ViewPager2 with FragmentStateAdapter to bind fragments. Each of my fragment has 3 recycler views laid out vertically. The problem is I'm not able to scroll the recycler view inside the fragments and also when I try to scroll the content vertically, the view pager changes tabs. How to fix this?

Comment: Answer is here, see support nested scrollable element part: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration

Comment: Did you find a fix. I am having the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Actually ViewPager2 Doesn't support nested Scrollable elements, So to support a scroll view inside a ViewPager2 object with the same orientation, you must call requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent() or wrap your nested scrolling view inside [this class](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ViewPager2/app/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/integration/testapp/NestedScrollableHost.kt).

Also, you can read this article to know about [how to Support nested scrollable elements inside ViewPager2](https://medium.com/@nasrabadiam/support-nested-scrollable-elements-inside-viewpager2-59fa34978899)

Comment: He is not asking about the nested scrolling man.

Answer (score 2):

Try view_pager.setUserInputEnabled(false),
it's worked for me.

from
https://medium.com/@ankurg22/viewpager2-on-the-outside-recyclerview-inside-a005adb5d63d

Comment: I converted my app from Viewpager to viewpager2. Each contains RV in fragment. Your answer fixed the scrolling issue.

Comment: This disables the horizontal swiping

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue I have three pages with vertical recyclerview and each page is a separate fragment inside viewpager2.

what i am doing is calculating the scroll in x and y direction and i am disabling the touch if scroll in y direction is more.

```java
public class CustomScrollHost extends FrameLayout {
    private float xDistance, yDistance, lastX, lastY;

    public CustomScrollHost(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomScrollHost(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollHost(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomScrollHost(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                xDistance = yDistance = 0f;
                lastX = ev.getX();
                lastY = ev.getY();
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                final float curX = ev.getX();
                final float curY = ev.getY();
                xDistance += Math.abs(curX - lastX);
                yDistance += Math.abs(curY - lastY);
                lastX = curX;
                lastY = curY;
                Log.d("CustomScrollHost", "xDistance " + xDistance);
                Log.d("CustomScrollHost", "yDistance " + yDistance);
                getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(yDistance > xDistance);
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Not even the NestedScrollableHost provided by Google worked. So thanks a lot!!