# Viewpager2 horizontal swipe not working inside parent viewpager2

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I have structure like **viewpager2 -> recyclerview -> viewpager2** as shown in image. Main Viewpager2 hold a recyclerview and inside recyclerview there is another viewpager2 that hold images list.

when I swipe on viewpager2 that is inside recyclerview its swipe the Main Viewpager2. But when i convert the main viewpager2 to viewpager than images swiping of inner viewpager2 working fine. please help me how can i achieve same functionality by viewpager2 rather than viewpager.

[image]

Comment: This is a classic problem . There are few hacks available for this Maybe [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151275/android-viewpager2-with-fragment-containing-a-recyclerview-not-scrolling) .  I faced similar issue recently ended up using `ViewPager` .

Comment: Thanks @ADM. By using NestedScrollableHost class child viewpager2 swipping work like a charm.

Comment: Because the link i have attached does not have an accepted answer.  You can add it as a proper answer(No one liner) and mark it accepted so that it can help others .